Asynchronous Query execution in Entity Framework Core C#
I want to understand whether the asynchronous execution happens same as C# code as in EFCore Queries.
Let's suppose I have the following queries:
var result1 = dbContext.Customers.Where(x=> x.FirstName.Contains("a"))
                                 .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    
var result2 = dbContext.Categories.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("a"))
                                  .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

and after couple of line of code if I await both
await result1.ConfigureAwait(false); 
await result2.ConfigureAwait(false);

My question is - do both queries result1 and result2 execute in parallel?
Does the asynchronous code execution work the same for EF Core query execution ?

Don't do that. The very idea is a bug. Slow queries won't run faster if you run more of them in parallel, they'll only increase delays. The query you tried ('FirstName LIKE '%a%'is *slow* no matter what, because it requires a full table scan and can't use indexes. What you typed will try *two full table scans at once*. At least useName LIKE '%a%' or Name LIKE '%a%'` to only do a single scan. Database connections don't allow multiple queries executing on the same connection anyway and DbContext is NOT a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work

This is an XY Problem. You have a problem X (slow wildcard queries that can't use indexes) and assume the solution is Y, to run more of them in parallel. When that fails, you asked about Y, not the real problem X. The solution to X is to NOT search in the middle in the first place. That's why applications only use prefix searches, that translate to LIKE 'a%'. This gets translated to a range query like Name>='a' and Name <'b' by the database. Range queries can use indexes.

If you're looking for a word in a sentence you can use your database's Full Text Search indexes and operators. Most databases have specialized full text search indexes that allow queries like WHERE CONTAINS (candidate_resume, '"SQL Server"'). A few databases like PostgreSQL offer specialized indexes for partial searches by breaking a field into trigrams (snippets 3 letters) and indexing those. Check pg_trg for this

@PanagiotisKanavos OP is just giving an example

Don't use .ConfigureAwait(false) unless its a unit test or non-gui app.

@IvanPetrov and that example suggests this is an XY problem. There's rarely any good reason to want concurrent queries on the same connection and the duplicate questions that ask for this almost always hide performance problems. The good reasons are parallel loading or export of millions of rows of data, something that just isn't done using ORMs.

@PanagiotisKanavos I think there is a problem in understanding for OP, not a real problem given the example code. Not sure, hope he sheds some light.

@IvanPetrov asking for concurrent execution with DbContext is always wrong - that's a Unit-of-Work, parallelism makes little sense. Think of someone asking how to load a DataTable in parallel. If someone asks for this, it's always something else

The C# code will execute concurrently. Potentially, in parallel.
However, EFCore DbContext instances do not allow concurrent executions:
From DbContext Class - Remarks:

Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same DbContext instance. This includes both parallel execution of async queries and any explicit concurrent use from multiple threads. Therefore, always await async calls immediately, or use separate DbContext instances for operations that execute in parallel. See Avoiding DbContext threading issues for more information and examples.


Connections don't allow concurrent queries either without some very specific coding. The OP seems to be trying to fix a bad Name LIKE '%a%' query with parallelism. That will only increase delays
